# Creating multiple custom fields via Tooling API in a single call

Tags: rest-api, tooling

I am attempting to create multiple custom fields in one REST API POST request to the `/services/data/v56.0/tooling/sobjects/customfield` endpoint using the following JSON body via Workbench AND Postman:

```
[{
  "FullName":"Account.Test1__c",
  "Metadata":{
     "externalId":false,
     "label":"Test 1",
     "required":false,
     "type":"Text"
  }
 },
 {
  "FullName":"Account.Test2__c",
  "Metadata":{
     "externalId":false,
     "label":"Test 2",
     "required":false,
     "type":"Text"
  }
}]
```

and I receive an error back:

```
[{"message":"Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]
```

Oddly enough it works fine by itself like so:

```
{
  "FullName":"Account.Test1__c",
  "Metadata":{
     "externalId":false,
     "label":"Test 1",
     "required":false,
     "type":"Text"
  }
}
```

But not if I wrap it in an array.. I have contacted SalesForce support and they have stated it should work like I am expecting but I am starting to wonder if they meant w/ SOAP and NOT REST. Is this working for others via REST?

Comment: _I have contacted support and they have stated it should work_  - that would be contrary to existing Tooling API documentation that operates on a single object at a time. If it indeed should work, have Support give you a working example and post it here.

Comment: What I got back the first time was:"For example, if you’re creating a custom text field, you would include the following fields in the custom field definition:
DeveloperName (required): The unique name of the custom field.
Label (required): The display name of the custom field.
Type (required): The data type of the custom field (e.g., Text, Number, Date).
You can include multiple custom field definitions in the request body, separated by commas or enclosed in an array."

Interestingly they suggested using DeveloperName instead of FullName. This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Tough to say whether their advice is correct and this is indeed an undocumented feature that works or they're wrong. Pursue the support case until one of these assertions is confirmed.

Comment: Thought so but figured I check to see if it was only me who was having trouble finding documentation on it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use composite request. Example:

```
String compositeRequestJson = '{'+
        '"compositeRequest" : ['+
            '{'+
                '"method" : "POST",'+
                '"url" : "/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField",'+
                '"referenceId" : "Field1",'+
                '"body" : {'+
                    '"FullName": "Contact.Custom_Field_1__c",'+
                    '"Metadata" : {'+
                        '"type" : "Text",'+
                        '"length" : 255,'+
                        '"label" : "Custom Field 1"'+
                    '}'+
                '}'+
            '},'+
            '{'+
                '"method" : "POST",'+
                '"url" : "/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField",'+
                '"referenceId" : "Field2",'+
                '"body" : {'+
                    '"FullName": "Contact.Custom_Field_2__c",'+
                    '"Metadata" : {'+
                        '"type" : "Text",'+
                        '"length" : 255,'+
                        '"label" : "Custom Field 2"'+
                    '}'+
                '}'+
            '}'+
        ']'+
    '}';
    
    // Make the Tooling API request
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v41.0/composite');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    request.setBody(compositeRequestJson);

    // Send the request
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
    
    // Handle the response
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 201) {
        System.debug('Field created successfully: ' + response.getBody());
    } else {
        System.debug('Error creating field: ' + response.getBody());
    }
```